# set a ripple effect on own picture in android

Tags: android

i want create a LIVE WALLPAPER with ripple effect on our own pix.
first prblem is - how to set wallpaper which is selected in iemageview.
and how to create a ripple effect on it.

import java.io.IOException;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b =(Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
            = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }});



    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setw);

    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For setting an image as wallpaper,

1. Add this to your manifest file

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>`
2. In `onClickListener` of your `ListView` get the absolute path of the image and set it as wallpaper using the below code,

   `WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
   InputStream ins = new URL("absolute/path/of/image").openStream();
   wpm.setStream(ins);`

Comment: im not using Listview. button1 will load a emage from gallery and paste it to imageview..and how could i get the absolute path of the emage ???

Comment: you alraedy got the absolute path in your program. The variable `picturePath ` in `onActivityResult()` represents the absolute path.